# Input array insert to database dynamic

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a problem with the next code to make dynamic:

HTML:

```
<input name="something1[]">
<input name="something2[]">
<input name="something3[]">

<input name="something1[]">
<input name="something2[]">
<input name="something3[]">
```

PHP:

```
for ( $i=0; $i < count($_POST['something1']) ; $i++ )
{
 $something1 = $_POST['something1'][$i];
 $something2 = $_POST['something2'][$i];
 $something3 = $_POST['something3'][$i];
 $query = DB::query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('$something1','$something2','$something3'));
}
```

that work perfect for me before, but now I need that dynamic regardless the number the inputs and don't need `$_POST['something1']` one by one. I try with `foreach` and then `for` loop inside but nothing.

Comment: Before you write any more database interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping practices](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You're just slamming this into `mysql_query`, aren't you?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking, but have a question: Why are you using both array access notation `[]` AND having an incrementing number (i.e. something1, something2, etc.)?

Comment: Because the inputs are arrays and i need insert the same rows many times with different values.

Comment: @MikeBrant you can clearly see in his exampple there are two of each `something1[]`, `something2[]`, and `something3[]` which would imply he has three (or an arbitary number of) array accessed input elements types.

Comment: @gbtimmon The question was updated after I posted my comments to reflect this. Initially, it was shown with one element for each name value.

Comment: Do you actually execute the query **within the loop**? (eg run `mysqli_query()` ). Please show more code

Comment: Is just for the example could be 7 inputs something1[] that matters is make dynamyc regardless number the inputs don't need $_POST['something1'] and like that one by one. Thanks

Comment: Yeah the code insert the values on table twice or according to the quantity the inputs

Comment: Alesanvil: what is actually the problem? Do you get an error? Do you get a blank screen? The code you just updated is missing a `"` in the DB::query line

Comment: always is good just i want that dynamic